# Local Wallet did not receive XMR

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I transferred XMR coins from my other wallet（freewallet） to my local wallet, and the payer showed that the payment was made, but the  shows no receipt

Monero transaction
Hash：f5b7ebf9290321ec791e482a616603afd6f1cc0a09a186f399291bda5e5e5343

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue.